# Accessing prototype method or function undefined

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm learning to work with prototype but have some problems in exporting and using it in other files. The require part works but I can't access to the properties or methods in my data.js.

If i want use `myFunction` I'm getting `myFunction is not a function` and for properties `undefined`

I also don't understand why `function(){};` instead of  `let Data = {};` works...

```
// data.js
let Data = function(){}; 

Data.prototype.integers = [0,1,3,2,8,4,11,22,74,98,111,5];

Data.prototype.myFunction= function (text){
  return text
}
module.exports.Data  = Data;


// main.js
let Numbers = require ("./data.js");
console.log(Numbers.myFunction("some text"), Numbers.integers ); // myFunction is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're adding members to `Data.prototype`.

Change `module.exports.Data = Data` with `module.exports.Data = new Data()`.

### Some advise

Unless you want to do stuff with object-oriented programming, I would refactor your code as follows:

```
// data.js
module.exports.Data = {
   integers: [0,1,3,2,8,4,11,22,74,98,111,5],

   myFunction: function (text){
        return text
   }
}
```

So you're code in `main.js` will work as well.

Comment: thank you :) but is it not better to use prototype for object-oriented programming ? I thought with prototype it will save memory because every instance will point to the same memory address

Comment: @Samy BTW, if you use literal objects and you reuse them, you're at the same point: you're not creating new objects. Inheritance isn't a swiss knife, anyway :D

Comment: @Samy Also, do you know `Object.create`? `Object.create(Data)` will create an object whose prototype is `Data`. You may still use prototypal inheritance without a constructor function!